# How to use a value of a variable as a casting type?

Tags: powershell

```
$myType="string"
[$myType]$myArray="hello","world"
```

I get `Missing type name after '['.`

```
$myType="string"
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[$myType]]$myCollection
```

I get `Unexpected token '$myType' in expression or statement.`

How do you make this concept work? It could save me some space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell 3.0 introduced that `-as` unchecked conversion operator that will convert a type name to a type for you:

```
$myType = 'string[]'
$numbers = 1,2,3 -as $myType
```

or

```
$myType = 'string'
$readOnlyStrings = @('some','strings') -as "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[$myType]"
```

Have a look at the [`about_Type_Operators` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators) for more information

---

Specifically for generic types, you can also [generate a specific type using the `MakeGenericType()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection), the target type of the argument is `[type[]]` so your string will be implicitly converted:

```
$myType = 'string'
$readOnlyType = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1].MakeGenericType(@($myType))
```

(the number after `` ` `` at the end denotes the number of type parameters)

Comment: Is PowerShell v3 introduce `-as`? Has you any reference for this? IIRC, only `-in` and `-notin` was introduced in v3, and them have explicit remark about that in help files.

Comment: @PetSerAl I am not certain, but `-as` was introduced at the same time as `-is` and `-isnot`, and I'm almost sure I've used `-is` in v3, but memory may betray me. Neither of the "What's new in PowerShell" versions 3 through 6 files mention them :(

Comment: The resulting variable holds the type (`ReadOnlyCollection<string>`) after assignment, so you could do `$readOnlyType::new($anArrayOrList)`. I only included it because your question specifically asked about a variable type parameter for a generic collection type.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, sorry to bother you but can `New-Object` be used instead of `new`? I can't get it to work with `New-Object` (that's how I've been instantiating all of my objects that require constructor parameters).

Comment: @bp2017 sure, but then there's no need to go through all this trouble - `New-Object` already takes just a string as its `TypeName` argument